# Fetch a field from a Multiple MySQL Query in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mysql-connector

I'm using NodeJS and need to fetch an `audioid` field from my first MySQL query, assign it to a variable and use that variable in my next MySQL query. So I've tried to use;

var newaudioid = results[0].audioid;

But the result is coming back as "undefined".

Here's the code;

```
 connection.query(sql, [1, 2], function(err, results, fields){
    if (!err) {             
        res.send(JSON.stringify(results[0]) + JSON.stringify(results[1]));
        console.log(results[0]);
        console.log(results[1]);
        var newaudioid = results[0].audioid;
        console.log('newaudioid = ' + newaudioid);

    }  else {
        console.log('Error while performing query.');
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

So `console.log('newaudioid = ' + newaudioid);` gives me back `newaudioid = undefined`

How can I fetch that `audioid` field from my first query?

Comment: Inspect **results** variable in debug session, probably there is some case issue?

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Try to log the value of `result` and see what it is returning.

Comment: What does the `console.log(results[0]):` return? Also, the `res.send` call is sending invalid JSON.

Comment: Yes if you could do a console.log(results) and post the result here so we can see if it is getting everything that is necessary, thanks.

Comment: results = [object Object],[object Object],
results0 = [object Object],[object Object]

Comment: SO I stringified IE: console.log('results0 = ' + JSON.stringify(results[0])); and got results0 = [{"audioid":144},{"audioid":147}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on your comment

> SO I stringified IE: console.log('results0 = ' +
> JSON.stringify(results[0])); and got results0 =
> [{"audioid":144},{"audioid":147}]

Inside results[0] you have 2 objects that themselves have another object inside, and they both have the same property name. The problem is that javascript does not know which one you are referring to when you are saying results[0].audioid

What you can do is use [0] again to get the first one again, so that would be: results[0][0]

Comment: results[0][0].audioid to get the specific value